# Responsive text with JS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set up a simple title on my site, that if the window is scaled or loaded below a certain px width, changes the text within to be shorter, then if scaled larger again pops back to the original HTML again. However, for some reason, this is proving to be very difficult.

Right now I have:

```
<script>
if ( $(window).width() > 480) {    
    $(".title").html("<a class='title' href='/'>LONGTEXTLONGTEXT</a>");
}
</script>

<script>
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
    if ( $(window).width() < 480) {    
        $(".title").html("<a class='title' href='/'>SHORTTEXT</a>");
    }
});
</script>
```

But for some reason it simply fails.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just use CSS media queries?

Comment: You've got a syntax error in your javascript - missing the `);` at the end of the `addEventListener()`  call. Fix that and it seems to work fine

Comment: `CSS` `em` will take care of what you need  ..

Comment: Might want to write an "else" statement for when its resized larger again.

Comment: @j08691 I tried using CSS ::after to change the content, but the issue is that it overwrites the anchor as well, leaving the changed text not a link any more, and I cannot add a span inside the anchor.

Comment: @Rhumborl Thank you! that seems to work. Edit: No, actually, it seems to still fail, reacted too soon.

Comment: @RNPF I guess @j08691 means to have the `<a>` always on the page but only set `display:block` if the window is < 480 using `@media(max-width: 480px)`

Comment: @Rhumborl I tried switching to jQuery when the event listened threw issues, with `$(window).resize(function() {
if ( $(window).width() < 480) {    
$(".title").html("<a class='title' href='/'>CD</a>");
}
}` but that doesnt work- any idea why it doesnt work even with a `);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, this is better done without JavaScript using CSS media queries (and without just changing the font size).

Put the long and short title links on the page and show/hide them depending on the width:

```css
div.title { background-color:#ff0; border-bottom:1px solid #000; }

/* this is for anything less than 480px */    
.title > .title { display:none; }
.title > .titlesmall { display:initial; }

/* greater than 480px */
@media screen and (min-width: 480px){
  .title > .title { display:initial; }
  .title > .titlesmall { display:none; }
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <a class='title' href='/'>Some really long title</a>
  <a class='titlesmall' href='/'>CD</a>
</div>
```

Alternatively fixing the syntax error, and preferably also using jQuery to listen to the `resize` event, should also work well enough:

```html
<div class="title">
  <a class='title' href='/'>Some really long title</a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  if ($(window).width() < 480) {
    $(".title").html("<a class='title' href='/'>CD</a>");
  }
</script>

<script>
  $(window).on('resize', function(event) {
    if ($(window).width() < 480) {
      $(".title").html("<a class='title' href='/'>CD</a>");
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! This would also solve the problem fully, and testing it, works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(larg);

 $(window).resize(larg);

 function larg(){
if ( $(window).width() < 480) {    
$(".title").html("<a class='title' href='/'>Smaller Text</a>");
}
else {
$(".title").html("<a class='title' href='/'>Text</a>");
}
}
</script>
```

Will replace the text on both load, and resize.

Answer (score 0):

This can and should be done with CSS. Here is how I would do it:

```
/* this is for anything less than 480px */    
.title{ font-size: 1em; }

...

/* greater than 480px */
@media screen and (min-width: 480px){ /*change min-width to em if you prefer*/
    .title{ font-size: 1.25em; }
}
```

You can chose whichever font sizes you want. Out of curiosity, was there a particular reason you wanted to do it with JavaScript?

Comment: Because I'm not trying to change the size of the font of the link, I'm trying to change the content of the text of the link. So instead of the title getting physcially smaller, the text instead will get smaller- EG: from "Bigtexthere" to "text"

Comment: Ah ok. Now I understand. Good to see you've got it working now!

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative way to achieve this by CSS:

Style:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
    .title-small {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .title-small {
      display: block;
    }

    .title {
      display: none;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1 class="title">Hello This is a long title.</h1>
<h1 class="title-small">Short title</h1>
```

Comment: I apparently worded  the question badly, my bad! The goal is not to change the font size, but change the text within the link. EG: `<a href="/">LONGTEXT</a>` to `<a href="/">ST</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Try font awesome. It is a good solution for responsive text.